# Как можно представить объедение union для массива и разбиением каждой ячейки массива на младший и старший разряды

Tags: c

Мне нужно сделать объедение union для массива. К каждой ячейки массива должен быть доступ с старшему и младшему байту.
Попытался сделать вот так:

```
    typedef union{
    uint16_t word[32];
    struct{
        uint8_t Ho[32];
        uint8_t Lo[32];
    };
} _DIO_MIN;
```

Получил следующею раскладку сначала идут слова word потом Ho потом Lo. А должно быть что каждая ячейка word[] могла раскладываться на Ho и Lo.

После эта структура помещается в структуру:

```
typedef struct DIO{
   _DIO_MIN DIO_MIN[63];       
   _DIO_MID DIO_MID[32];            
 } _SysMem;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так годится?

```
typedef union
{
    uint16_t word;
    struct {
        uint8_t lo;
        uint8_t hi;
    };
} array[32];
```

Пример [тут](https://ideone.com/GDOoPP).

Comment: Мне надо еще вставить в структуру '_DIO_MIN' чтобы получилось что-то типа typedef struct DIO{
   _DIO_MIN DIO_MIN[63]; 
} _SysMem;